# odata.type missing from Directory audit logs in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We are using the [List directoryAudits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/graph/api/directoryaudit-list?view=graph-rest-beta) API to retrieve audit logs from Azure.  The @odata.type is no longer present on the targetResource.  Is there a way to configure the request to include this property?

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/graph/api/directoryaudit-get?view=graph-rest-beta) for an example of the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce the issue on my side, I don't think you can configure the request to include the `@odata.type`, the API is a `Beta` version, it may be related to itself.

[image]

I have opened an [issue](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/3666) in the GitHub, you can track it for the process.

**Update**:

As mentioned of this [link](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/3666#issuecomment-448596273), Seems Microsoft is in the middle of updating the audit schema.